# Async await in Windows Phone web access APIs

Tags: c#, async-await, windows-phone-8

Is there support for the async/await pattern in WP8?

I need to get XML from a web-based API and it looks like that `WebClient` or `WebRequest` do not support it.

Are there classes that support async/await usable for web access in the WP8 BCL? And if not, is there a library I can use?

I know it is not that hard to create wrappers to support it, but this seems like a thing that would be included in the SDK.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Are there classes that support async/await usable for web access in the WP8 BCL?

This is a concern that has been raised during the closed beta of the WP8 SDK, so I can answer that unfortunately, no.

But as you mentioned, it is reasonably easy to make your own wrappers.

For instance:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static Task<string> DownloadStringTask(this WebClient webClient, Uri uri)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                tcs.SetException(e.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                tcs.SetResult(e.Result);
            }
        };

        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(uri);

        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you put async operation in its own thread? I don't know why, but this looks horrible!

Answer (score 8):

There is some support for WP8 in the `Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Phone.dll` provided as part of the [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async` NuGet package](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/1.0.12-beta) described [in this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/22/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx).

In particular, it includes `WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I found this and helped me

```
private async Task<T> ExecuteAsync<T>(RestRequest request)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        _client.ExecuteAsync(request, resp =>
        {
            var value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(resp.Content);
            if (value.ErrorCode > 0)
            {
                var ex = new ToodledoException(value.ErrorCode, value.ErrorDesc);
                tcs.SetException(ex);
            }
            else
                tcs.SetResult(value);
        });
        return await tcs.Task;
    }
```

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Asynchronous_Programming_For_Windows_Phone_8
also I found this extension helpful http://nuget.org/packages/WP8AsyncWebClient/

Answer (score 0):

> Is there support for the async/await pattern in WP8?

Just to clarify, there is full C# 5.0 support on Windows Phone 8. The WinRT APIs largely depend on async/await, such as syncing to PeopleHub, or using the I/O APIs.

But the Silverlight and old .NET APIs have not been updated to use async/await for classes like the WebClient.

Comment: I get that there is language support, but KooKiz asserted, there is no API support.

Comment: If you read my *entire* post, you'll see that there *is* API support, for *some* APIs.

Answer (score 0):

WP8 has native async/await support with some limitations, like missing HttpClient and possibly other classes.
WP7 had support for async/await in VS2010 using AsyncCTP, but in VS2012 it was re-added recently as Microsoft.Bcl.Async:
https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/1.0.12-beta