# how to Create a ListBox in windows phone for a Async Json datagetting from a url?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, listbox

I Done Json Parsing By [this way](http://www.dfg-team.com/json-feeds-on-windows-phone/?lang=en)

and in that if i try with (as a example)

```
public string id { get; set; }
```

i can able to make a constant data not a listBox...

I Already Done an android application.. for a Json form a Url.. This is my Json data(similar to this.)

```
{
"returnCode": "success",
"Data": {
"results": [
{
    "moredetails": [
        {
            "newoffers": [

            ],
            "recentoffers_count": 0,
            "sku": "30072246"
        },
        {
            "newoffers": [
                {
                    "availability": "Available",
                    "currency": "USD"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "newoffers": [
                {
                    "availability": "Available",
                    "currency": "USD"
                }
            ],
            "offers_count": 1,
            "name": "google.com"
        }
    ],
    ..."features": {
        ..
    },
    "length": "20",
    "geo": [
        "usa"
    ],
    .."images": ["http://timenerdworld.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/wpid-photo-jan-14-2013-1117-am.jpg"],
    ..
}
],
...
}
}
```

Like this Have a Huge JSON data this is Just a one loop of a JSon data ... i have a N number of loops of a JSON data So i want to display the data..

So in android i am Parsing Json with Hashmap and now in C# i am parsing similar way..
[image]

So at here I want a List Box.. In android i used ListView + onclick single item view By [this Url](http://developer-android-tutorial.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-how-to-parse-json-and-show.html)

and in windows i found a List Box + onclick single item By [this URL](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Listbox_handling_in_Windows_Phone) But it not JSON its a XML Json i want this for JSON..

and want to add i want to Create a Same List Box With a JSON data With and async task which is Based on

```
 JObject json = JObject.Parse(eArgs.Result);
        JArray category_list = (JArray)json["category_list"];

        this.jAbout.Text = (string)json["about"];
```

Like that...

So that this will Look same like android Application... is there any way to make the Same flicker app for JSON in windows phone  application.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows phone 7 exist **ListBox** and **LongListSelector** (from the windows phone toolkit) controls for representing different sort of collections.
ListBox is more simply to use.
**ListBox** has **ItemsSource** property.

*You have to work with UIElements only from the main thread. But you can prepare everything in the background thread*

How to work with ListBox:

1. You can put there any **IEnumerable<*yourDataModelClass*>** instance or bind some property with the type, that inherits from IEnumerable (for example List<*yourDataModelClass*> or ObservableCollection<*yourDataModelClass*>. Second one is better for binding). "*yourDataModelClass*" is some class, that contains all properties of the ListBox item. If you liked LINQ, with help of which [this guys](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Listbox_handling_in_Windows_Phone) (developer.nokia.com) deserializing XML, you can use [LINQ to JSON](http://json.codeplex.com).
   And for the ListBox you have to set ItemTemplate property (better do it from XAML) (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx).
2. As I already mentioned, you can bind some collection to the ItemsSource property. So you put this collection into **DataContext** property of your ListBox, In XAML you can write like this <*ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"/*>. So if collection is ObservableCollection, so there is already implemented INotifyPropertyChanged, and this collection will notify its owner, if there appended some items (here is you also have to create some ItemTemplate). *So if you already set this collection to the DataContex, you can't add something into it in the background thread.* It's better to read something about **MVVM pattern**, it's cool \m/
3. There is another way to work with ListBox: you can add ListBox items to its property called **Items**.

For asynchronous work here exist a couple ways:

1. **BackgroundWorker** class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.95).aspx)
2. **async tasks** (you'll need this library for it http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) (here is an example of a task using [Async await in Windows Phone web access APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173614/async-await-in-windows-phone-web-access-apis)).

So this ways will help you to do whatever you want asynchronously. Enjoy =)

And don't forget to go back to the main thread, when your JSON is parsed and you ready to show it to a user ( Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Action); - this is how to go back to the UI thread whenever you want, but my advice is to read about BackgroundWorker and  async tasks)